# will form authentication related tasks work while authentication mode is windows?

Tags: asp.net

this is just a query. suppose I didn't specified the authentication mode in web.config file. So as per rule default authentication mode will be windows. Now if I want to work with form authentication related tasks, is it permissible ? `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` for example.